# Is "Grumps" a nickname?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, american-english

I found this name in a contemporary [American novel](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_Gracious_Neighbor/8SezzgEACAAJ?hl=it). The main character is looking at old objects that belonged to a friend, and among the many things she finds is a gift tag that says 'To Minnie from **Grumps**'.
Maybe Grumps is a proper name, but I wonder if it could also be someone's nickname, for example a grandfather (a mispronunciation of Grandpa?). The novel is set in Texas, so it could also be a local idiom.

> Inadvertently, she’d stumbled upon a private time capsule, a haphazard collection of detritus from Minnie’s early years: her National Honor Society membership card, her lifesaving and water safety card issued by the American Red Cross in 1994, her residence hall ID from Whitman College, a tag for a pet named Tiger with a Houston address, a Brownie pin, a tiny copper bracelet, three crisp two-dollar bills, a smashed penny, several swimming medals from middle school, a gift tag marked “To Minnie from Grumps,” an old pipe that still smelled like tobacco, a lock of blond hair, a chain with several small mismatched keys, a tin photograph of a grim-faced couple who looked a bit like Minnie, and more. She closed the box and put it down, letting her fingertips trace the design before moving on.

Comment: Not a usual proper name; almost certainly a nickname. 'Grumps' is often used in the USA as a nickname for someone who is 'grumpy (bad-tempered).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because without a link to the source for context, it's unanswerable

Comment: I added a link to the source, and I can provide the whole paragraph, but it wouldn't help: it's just a sentence without a real context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no other reference to this Grumps person, there can be no definitive answer, but we can make some educated guesses.

Grumps is not a common first name (or "given name", if you prefer), but there's little stopping someone from using an uncommon name.  There was a famous professional skier named Picabo, which is pronounced like *peekaboo*.  So, it's certainly possible that there's someone whose legal name is *Grumps*.

But it's more likely it's a nickname.  It's probably a nickname for Minnie's grandfather.  American grandparents are probably called *Grandmother* and *Grandfather* much less frequently than they're called by other, more affectionate terms.  One very common alternative for *Grandfather* is *Grandpa*, which is sometimes shortened to *Gramps*.  *Grumps* would likely be a variation on *Gramps*; either an intentional joke (old men are often pretty grumpy), or an small child's unintentional mispronunciation, which stuck.  I have never heard *Grumps* used in this way, but some quick Googling found a couple references:

> One disadvantage that grandfathers have is that their names are easily modified into something less than flattering. Gramps, for example, has been known to morph into Grumps

[111 Nicknames for Grandpa](https://www.verywellfamily.com/choose-the-perfect-grandfather-name-1695526)

> Let the kids choose a name and make it cool..Puff G-Diddy and Glam-Ma;G-ma and G-pa;Grams and Grumps

[Traditional or Cool, Gramps or Grumps – a List of Grandparent Names!](https://mumcentral.com.au/grandparent-names/)

The context also supports this name belonging to a grandparent. Grandparents are likely to send a gift to a grandchild, and to sign the name their grandchild calls them by.